# erlang message sending and receiving reply

Tags: erlang

I am trying to make a master process here which willspawn the 5 processes and then these process will make a call to the people in the list. The text file is as follows :

> {john, [jill,joe,bob]}. {jill, [bob,joe,bob]}. {sue,
>   [jill,jill,jill,bob,jill]}. {bob, [john]}. {joe, [sue]}.
>
> Blockquote

in it john is a process and will send a message to Jill, joe and bob. Same with the other processes. So far I was able to spawn the process and get the elements from the sublist but I donot know how to send the messages from processes to the sublists .I am a beginner in erlang and I am facing too much problem in it I have read a lot about the processes and concurrency and from many resources but this is way too much for me .the required output looks like this :

> bob received intro message from jill [738000] joe received intro
>   message from john [741004] bob received intro message from john
>   [770008] joe received intro message from jill [779007] john received
>   intro message from bob [736102] john received reply message from joe
>   [741004] john received reply message from bob [770008] jill received
>   intro message from sue [737001] bob received intro message from jill
>   [816004] bob received reply message from john [736102] bob received
>   intro message from sue [897005] jill received intro message from john
>   [739000]

The time stamp of message sent and received should match . 
any help would be appreciated a code snippet performing the message sending and receiving would be highly appreciated . Thank you .

-module(exchange).
    -import(lists,[nth/2]).
    -export([start/0,for/2,for1/2,process/0]).

```
start()->
A=file:consult("calls.txt"),
T=element(2,A),

   L=length(T),
   %io:fwrite("~w",[L]),
   for(L,T).


for(0,_)->
   [];
   for(L,Term) when L > 0 ->

   S=nth(L,Term),
   S1=element(1,S),
   io:fwrite(" ~w~n",[S1]),
   Q=element(2,S),
   R=length(Q),
   B=nth(1,Q),
   for1 (R,Q),
   Pid=spawn(exchange,process,[]),
   register(S1,Pid),
   S1 ! {sender, S1,R,Q},

   for(L-1,Term).


for1(0,_)->
[];
for1(L1,Term1) when L1 >0 ->
S2=nth(L1,Term1),
  process()->
   receive
   {sender, S1,R,Q}->
    io:fwrite("~w received intro message from ",[S1]),
    process()
  end;
for1 (L1-1,Term1).
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of changes you could make to make the code clearer, and hopefully that would make it easier to find the problem.  Normally you'd use the function `element` very rarely, preferring pattern matching instead.  So change this:

```
A=file:consult("calls.txt"),
T=element(2,A),
```

to:

```
{ok, T} = file:consult("calls.txt"),
```

This has the advantage that if `file:consult` returns an error, the code will catch it quickly, instead of trying to proceed even though it doesn't have the data from the file.

Walking through a list and doing something for each element is a common pattern in Erlang.  Instead of keeping an index and using `lists:nth`, you'd normally call `lists:foreach`, which is a higher-level function that calls your function on each list element.  So instead of:

```
   L=length(T),
   %io:fwrite("~w",[L]),
   for(L,T).
```

you could write:

```
lists:foreach(fun for/1, T).
```

Then your `for` function (which perhaps would get another name, since it's no longer doing the looping) would start with:

```
for(S) ->
   S1=element(1,S),
   io:fwrite(" ~w~n",[S1]),
   %% ...
```

Here, you could do the pattern matching in the function head, to avoid calling `element`:

```
for({S1, Q}) ->
   io:fwrite(" ~w~n",[S1]),
   R=length(Q),
   B=nth(1,Q),
   for1 (R,Q),
   Pid=spawn(exchange,process,[]),
   register(S1,Pid),
   S1 ! {sender, S1,R,Q}.
```

Here we have the `length`+`nth` pattern again, this time for `for1`, so we could replace that too with `lists:foreach`:

```
for({S1, Q}) ->
   io:fwrite(" ~w~n",[S1]),
   lists:foreach(fun for1/1, Q),
   Pid=spawn(exchange,process,[]),
   register(S1,Pid),
   S1 ! {sender, S1,R,Q}.
```

Hope that helps - the `for1` function doesn't compile when I try it, but hopefully this should get you started.